# Разбиение строки на массив слов по пробелам

Tags: массивы, строки, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Нужно написать программу, которая разбивает входящую строку на слова по пробелам и сохраняет слова в массиве. Как это сделать с помощью полного перебора строки методом `charAt`?

Comment: `с помощью полного перебора строки методом charAt?` - вы вообще о чем, метод `charAt` - выводит лишь символ по индексу, перебирать он не умеет.

Answer (score 8):

Как это сделать перебором — а зачем, если есть готовый метод [String::split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), который разбивает?

```
String[] s = yourString.split(" ");
```

Или это учебное задание и нужно именно используя метод `charAt`?

Но если это учебное задание для особых преподавателей, тогда где то так:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static String[] divide(String s) {
        ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = 0;
        boolean f = false;

        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
            if (s.charAt(j) == ' ') {
                if (j > i) {
                    tmp.add(s.substring(i, j));
                }
                i = j + 1;
            }
        }
        if (i < s.length()) {
            tmp.add(s.substring(i));
        }
        return tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.size()]);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String s = "   1  aaa  2 bbbbbb 3    cccc  4 5 6     7     x";
        String[] r = divide(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
            System.out.println('"' + r[i] + '"');
    }
}
```

Правда я использую `ArrayList<String>`, что бы не заморачиваться с массивом. Но и это можно обойти, если нужно.

Comment: @KoVadim split принимает параметр типа String, а не char.

Comment: именно учебное)

Comment: и нужно именно через charAt? может полностью опубликуете задание?

Comment: Нужно написать программу, которая разбивает входящую строку на слова по пробелам и сохраняет слова в массиве,
 с помощью полного перебора строки методом charAt

Comment: @KoVadim: я бы поставил плюс, честно. Но мне пришло в голову, что человек, не умеющий написать такое, будет завтра считаться программистом, и писать софт для моего банка или моего провайдера. Теперь удерживаюсь от того, чтобы поставить минус вопросу.

Comment: очень все спорно. Я лично видел человека, который руководит большим проектом на java (около 20 серверов, порядка 10млн пользователей в сутки, мобильные клиенты...), но при этом не знает операторов & и |. То есть он о них знает, но как ими пользоваться - нет. А это описано в любой нормальной книге.

Но если это задание от преподавателя, то я бы (на месте преподавателя) формулировал так. "есть метод String.split, который разобрали на лекции. Написать аналог, можно без регулярных выражений, провести тесты, замеры скорости".