# Разбить строку на слова java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, помогите
Я прочитал строку из файла и теперь мне надо разбить ее на слова по пробелу, так же в слове поменять буквы местами и записать в файл.
Как можно разбить на слова и поменять буквы местами(без разницы какие, просто для пример) ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String text = new String();
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            text += in.nextLine();
        }
        in.close();
        char[] words;
        char line;
        String delimeter = " ";
        words = text.toCharArray();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("crypt.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if(words[i] == ' ') {
                System.out.print(words[i]);
                break;
            }
     }
}
```

Пытался вывести хотя бы первые буквы до пробела, но не вышло

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, **приведите код, который вы написали**, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/190062/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC

Comment: "поменять буквы местами" как поменять, третью букву на пятую, а первую на вторую?

Answer (score 0):

Поменять буквы местами можно с помощью charAt([0]) например, или вывести в обратном порядке как в примере

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "am arr";

    String[] arrayStr = s.split(" ");

    for (String i : arrayStr) {
        String t = new StringBuilder(i).reverse().toString();
        System.out.println(t);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

> Вот так можешь разбить строку через пробелы , если я тебя правильно понял)

```
 class Ideone
 {
 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
     {
     for(char c: "Hello World".toCharArray())
      {
        System.out.print(c + " ");
       //Output H e l l o  W o r l d
      }
    }
 }
```